# Increasing sequence for each different column value

Tags: sql-server

I have a product Interaction table like this

```
CREATE TABLE ProductInteraction
    (
      Id BIGINT not null IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
      ProductId BIGINT NOT NULL,
      UserAction varchar(100),
      ProcessingOrder INT
    )
```

Assume, whenever user does some activity on a product it is logged here. Now what i want to do is set a sequence for the `ProcessingOrder` for each `ProductId`

**For example**

User clicks on `product1` 
User zoom on `product1` 
User added to cart on `product1`

User added to cart on `product2` (as this is a different product , the sequence is starting from seed) 
User removed from cart on `product2` 
User changed quantity in cart on `product1` (this product has last sequence 3, so this rcord will have 4)

The records should be like this

```
Id, ProductId, UserAction, ProcessingOrder
    1   100        click       1
    2   100        zoom        2
    3   100        addCart     3
    4   200        addCart     1
    5   200        removeCart  2
    6   100        chgQuantity 4
```

I want to be a automatic property (like auto increment), dont want to manage this sequence myself

How can i do this?

Comment: I'm not sure that any method to achieve this in the table itself would be more efficient than, say, a view with row_number() over (partition by productid order by id)

Comment: yeah view is one of the best option.Updating ProcessingOrder in Trigger is best option.you hvn't mention how data will be inserted in ProductInteraction single insert/bulk insert.Also when you have Id  auto increament then is really ProcessOrderID require.do you hv to show numeric value or just in that order.